# Button appears in two important locations and feels redundant

Tags: forms, navigation, buttons, login, authentication

I'm building a log in page but ran into an issue with my nav bar. As you can see the "Log In" button **appears in two locations**.

What's the best way to approach this? To me it looks odd to have it shown twice, yet its a necessary part of the nav bar.

I can correct this by removing the button for just that page...but then that feels like a complicated solution because it requires modifying template code with an if statement.

What should be done here instead?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 1: Keep only Login in the4 navbar

A common pattern that is used across the board is the use of only the **Login** CTA in the nav bar. Once in the login screen, the user is given the option to **Sign Up** or **Register** if they didn't have an account.

Example: 
[image: Only login in navbar]

### Option 2: Keep both, but don't make them buttons

Keep both the Login and the Sign Up in the nav bar but devalue (not have them look like a button) them. Generally, Login is devalued as **Sign Up** is a way of inviting new users.

Example with both CTA's devalued:
[image: Both sign up and login]

Example with Login devalued:
[image: Navbar with login devalued]

Also, a side note: Don't have the forgot password as a button. It should be a link

Comment: First time hearing of devaluing. Makes a lot of sense and I chose to do the stackexchange style where log in text is not a button but sign up is.